# Distinction between meaning of racial minority vs. racialized minority

Tags: meaning, expressions

**Is there a substantive distinction in the meaning of racial vs. racialized when referring to a minority group?**
<sub>Note: question is intended to focus on meaning, not part of speech i.e. verb+object vs. adjective</sub>

According to [Lexico](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/racial) definitions are as follows:

> **Racialize**

> VERB [WITH OBJECT]

> Make racial in tone or character.

‘the ways in which language is used to colonize, racialize, and commodify the other' e.g. ‘this kind of racialized discourse was common to nineteenth-century thinkers’

> 1.1 Categorize or divide according to race.
> ‘a highly racialized society’

<!>

> **Racial**

> ADJECTIVE

> Relating to race.
> ‘a racial minority’
>
> 1.1 On the grounds of or connected with difference in race.
> e.g. ‘racial abuse’

I read these as an indication that *racialize* is an effort to include race as a important characteristic as opposed to *racial* which I perceive as passive where race is inherently a component.

I would appreciate any commentary and examples that help make the distinction.

**Edit**: Here is an example newspaper article, which includes the term [*racialized minority*](http://montrealgazette.com/opinion/opinion-racialized-minorities-in-montreal-continue-to-suffer)

Comment: The distinction is in the part of speech. The first is a verb: what someone does or tries to do to the minority. The second is an adjective which describes the minority.

Comment: @WeatherVane I do see that they are different parts of speech; that is part of the definitions.  What I don't fully appreciate is the distinction between the **meaning** of racialized minority and racial minority.

Comment: 'Racial' means having to do with race. 'Racialized' means made to be something having to do with race. 'A racial minority' means a minority that is so because of race. 'A racialized minority' just doesn't sound right semantically. A minority is probably so not by choice and not by external changing factors (though one can certainly make a long term case to make sense out of that). How do you racialize a minority? People slowly realize that a subgroup is recognized because of race? Where are you seeing 'racialized minority'? Can you give a link?

Comment: I would say that a **racialised minority** is a political **racist** gambit that is intended to undermine the group's position.

Comment: @Mitch Link to the use of the term added.  The first part of your answer is helpful.  I agree with you re: 'sounding right', which was the part of the basis for the question.

Comment: You should add a quote from that article. Things always make more sense in context. Whatever the literal meanings of words, I think I would have expected 'ethnic' instead of 'racialized'. But it seems the term 'racialized' is specific to Canada.

Comment: Your suggestion that racialize is an effort to include race as a important characteristic as opposed to racial… where race is inherently a component is prolly correct but in 60 years of listening, I've never before heard of a *racialized minority* and I wonder where you saw that used, whether or not its meaning was clear?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin There is an article in the "Edit" link: http://montrealgazette.com/opinion/opinion-racialized-minorities-in-montreal-continue-to-suffer

Comment: Based on the fact it's from French-speaking Canada, it's probably a translation of a French term such as *Communautés racialisées* https://www.rondpointdelitinerance.ca/itinerance/communaut%C3%A9s-racialis%C3%A9es

Answer (score 1):

Because the subject is a hot point, often limited to academia, and about a verb that has yet to enter general consciousness (even in some dictionaries), this question invites speculative answers and perhaps even emotionally charged responses (i.e, downvotes, or rude remarks). Even so, I will risk it, but I would ask for mercy, please.

First, a quick look at Google Books shows *racialized minority* with a [healthy 5,000+ hits.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22racialized%20minority%22)

In the broader sense:

There is **no** "**substantive** distinction," or more specifically, significant **semantic** difference between the adjective *racial* and the verb *racialized*. As pointed out in the comments section, a *racial minority* implies that such a portion of the population has been already *racialized*. In **some** contexts, they could be used interchangeably.

For the distinctions (differences):

The most meaningful contribution of verbing *race* (racialized) is to expose the largely unconscious practice of [producing race](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057/9780230115385_3). Consider, then, that the phrase *racial minority* is significantly older than *racialized minority*. So, they invoke different times and distinct constructions of meaning (to which we cannot go on here)

In fact if you look at them together from the perspective of [Critical Race Theory,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_race_theory) you could appreciate how the term *racialized minority* is unmasking the trouble with *racial minority*, namely, that it assumes and accepts the racialization process.

1- *Racial minority* - group taken for granted to belong in a racial category

2- *Racialized minority* - a group that is being assigned/categorized in a racial hierarchy

By using the verb (racialized) you are doing both, pointing to the process and distancing from it.

Answer (score -1):

"Racial" is an adjective. "Racialised" (or "racialized" if you prefer) is the past participle of a transitive verb — one having a subject, a verb and an object.  If you have a "racialised group", this implies that someone has done something to it to differentiate it by race. Seems absurd to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But see Lexico's sense/subsense 1.1.